# Can't covert from <fctr> to <date> adequately

Tags: r, date, xts

This is a little strange. I converted data from .csv to .xts other times before, but this time for some reasons cannot.

Here is my data set (`dput()` of half the real data set, since the complete one was out of characters limits. And yeah, the problem persists):

```
structure(list(time = structure(c(347L, 369L, 391L, 413L, 435L, 
457L, 479L, 501L, 522L, 543L, 564L, 585L, 605L, 624L, 641L, 12L, 
33L, 54L, 75L, 96L, 117L, 138L, 159L, 180L, 201L, 222L, 243L, 
264L, 285L, 306L, 327L, 349L, 371L, 393L, 415L, 437L, 459L, 481L, 
503L, 524L, 545L, 566L, 587L, 607L, 626L, 643L, 14L, 35L, 56L, 
77L, 98L, 119L, 140L, 161L, 182L, 203L, 224L, 245L, 266L, 287L, 
308L, 329L, 351L, 373L, 395L, 417L, 439L, 461L, 483L, 505L, 526L, 
547L, 568L, 589L, 609L, 628L, 16L, 37L, 58L, 79L, 100L, 121L, 
142L, 163L, 184L, 205L, 226L, 247L, 268L, 289L, 310L, 331L, 353L, 
375L, 397L, 419L, 441L, 463L, 485L, 507L, 528L, 549L, 570L, 591L, 
611L, 630L, 645L, 18L, 39L, 60L, 81L, 102L, 123L, 144L, 165L, 
186L, 207L, 228L, 249L, 270L, 291L, 312L, 333L, 355L, 377L, 399L, 
421L, 443L, 465L, 487L, 509L, 530L, 551L, 572L, 593L, 613L, 632L, 
20L, 41L, 62L, 83L, 104L, 125L, 146L, 167L, 188L, 209L, 230L, 
251L, 272L, 293L, 314L, 335L, 357L, 379L, 401L, 423L, 445L, 467L, 
489L, 511L, 532L, 553L, 574L, 595L, 615L, 634L, 647L, 1L, 22L, 
43L, 64L, 85L, 106L, 127L, 148L, 169L, 190L, 211L, 232L, 253L, 
274L, 295L, 316L, 337L, 359L, 381L, 403L, 425L, 447L, 469L, 491L, 
513L, 534L, 555L, 576L, 597L, 617L, 636L, 3L, 24L, 45L, 66L, 
87L, 108L, 129L, 150L, 171L, 192L, 213L, 234L, 255L, 276L, 297L, 
318L, 339L, 361L, 383L, 405L, 427L, 449L, 471L, 493L, 515L, 536L, 
557L, 578L, 5L, 26L, 47L, 68L, 89L, 110L, 131L, 152L, 173L, 194L, 
215L, 236L, 257L, 278L, 299L, 320L, 341L, 363L, 385L, 407L, 429L, 
451L, 473L, 495L, 517L, 538L, 559L, 580L, 600L, 619L, 638L, 7L, 
28L, 49L, 70L, 91L, 112L, 133L, 154L, 175L, 196L, 217L, 238L, 
259L, 280L, 301L, 322L, 343L, 365L, 387L, 409L, 431L, 453L, 475L, 
497L, 519L, 540L, 561L, 582L, 602L, 621L, 9L, 30L, 51L, 72L, 
93L, 114L, 135L, 156L, 177L, 198L, 219L, 240L, 261L, 282L, 303L, 
324L, 345L, 367L, 389L, 411L, 433L, 455L, 477L, 499L, 520L, 541L, 
562L, 583L, 603L, 622L, 640L, 10L, 31L, 52L, 73L, 94L, 115L, 
136L, 157L, 178L, 199L, 220L, 241L, 262L, 283L, 304L, 325L, 346L, 
368L, 390L, 412L, 434L, 456L, 478L, 500L, 521L, 542L, 563L, 584L, 
604L, 623L, 11L, 32L, 53L, 74L, 95L, 116L, 137L, 158L, 179L, 
200L, 221L, 242L, 263L, 284L, 305L, 326L, 348L, 370L, 392L, 414L, 
436L, 458L, 480L, 502L, 523L, 544L, 565L, 586L, 606L, 625L, 642L, 
13L, 34L, 55L, 76L, 97L, 118L, 139L, 160L, 181L, 202L, 223L, 
244L, 265L, 286L, 307L, 328L, 350L, 372L, 394L, 416L, 438L, 460L, 
482L, 504L, 525L, 546L, 567L, 588L, 608L, 627L, 644L, 15L, 36L, 
57L, 78L, 99L, 120L, 141L, 162L, 183L, 204L, 225L, 246L, 267L, 
288L, 309L, 330L, 352L, 374L, 396L, 418L, 440L, 462L, 484L, 506L, 
527L, 548L, 569L, 590L, 610L, 629L, 17L, 38L, 59L, 80L, 101L, 
122L, 143L, 164L, 185L, 206L, 227L, 248L, 269L, 290L, 311L, 332L, 
354L, 376L, 398L, 420L, 442L, 464L, 486L, 508L, 529L, 550L, 571L, 
592L, 612L, 631L, 646L, 19L, 40L, 61L, 82L, 103L, 124L, 145L, 
166L, 187L, 208L, 229L, 250L, 271L, 292L, 313L, 334L, 356L, 378L, 
400L, 422L, 444L, 466L, 488L, 510L, 531L, 552L, 573L, 594L, 614L, 
633L, 21L, 42L, 63L, 84L, 105L, 126L, 147L, 168L, 189L, 210L, 
231L, 252L, 273L, 294L, 315L, 336L, 358L, 380L, 402L, 424L, 446L, 
468L, 490L, 512L, 533L, 554L, 575L, 596L, 616L, 635L, 648L, 2L, 
23L, 44L, 65L, 86L, 107L, 128L, 149L, 170L, 191L, 212L, 233L, 
254L, 275L, 296L, 317L, 338L, 360L, 382L, 404L, 426L, 448L, 470L, 
492L, 514L, 535L, 556L, 577L, 598L, 618L, 637L, 4L, 25L, 46L, 
67L, 88L, 109L, 130L, 151L, 172L, 193L, 214L, 235L, 256L, 277L, 
298L, 319L, 340L, 362L, 384L, 406L, 428L, 450L, 472L, 494L, 516L, 
537L, 558L, 579L, 599L, 6L, 27L, 48L, 69L, 90L, 111L, 132L, 153L, 
174L, 195L, 216L, 237L, 258L, 279L, 300L, 321L, 342L, 364L, 386L, 
408L, 430L, 452L, 474L, 496L, 518L, 539L, 560L, 581L, 601L, 620L, 
639L, 8L, 29L, 50L, 71L, 92L, 113L, 134L, 155L, 176L, 197L, 218L, 
239L, 260L, 281L, 302L, 323L, 344L, 366L, 388L, 410L, 432L, 454L, 
476L, 498L), .Label = c("01/01/2015", "01/01/2016", "01/02/2015", 
"01/02/2016", "01/03/2015", "01/03/2016", "01/04/2015", "01/04/2016", 
"01/05/2015", "01/06/2015", "01/07/2015", "01/08/2014", "01/08/2015", 
"01/09/2014", "01/09/2015", "01/10/2014", "01/10/2015", "01/11/2014", 
"01/11/2015", "01/12/2014", "01/12/2015", "02/01/2015", "02/01/2016", 
"02/02/2015", "02/02/2016", "02/03/2015", "02/03/2016", "02/04/2015", 
"02/04/2016", "02/05/2015", "02/06/2015", "02/07/2015", "02/08/2014", 
"02/08/2015", "02/09/2014", "02/09/2015", "02/10/2014", "02/10/2015", 
"02/11/2014", "02/11/2015", "02/12/2014", "02/12/2015", "03/01/2015", 
"03/01/2016", "03/02/2015", "03/02/2016", "03/03/2015", "03/03/2016", 
"03/04/2015", "03/04/2016", "03/05/2015", "03/06/2015", "03/07/2015", 
"03/08/2014", "03/08/2015", "03/09/2014", "03/09/2015", "03/10/2014", 
"03/10/2015", "03/11/2014", "03/11/2015", "03/12/2014", "03/12/2015", 
"04/01/2015", "04/01/2016", "04/02/2015", "04/02/2016", "04/03/2015", 
"04/03/2016", "04/04/2015", "04/04/2016", "04/05/2015", "04/06/2015", 
"04/07/2015", "04/08/2014", "04/08/2015", "04/09/2014", "04/09/2015", 
"04/10/2014", "04/10/2015", "04/11/2014", "04/11/2015", "04/12/2014", 
"04/12/2015", "05/01/2015", "05/01/2016", "05/02/2015", "05/02/2016", 
"05/03/2015", "05/03/2016", "05/04/2015", "05/04/2016", "05/05/2015", 
"05/06/2015", "05/07/2015", "05/08/2014", "05/08/2015", "05/09/2014", 
"05/09/2015", "05/10/2014", "05/10/2015", "05/11/2014", "05/11/2015", 
"05/12/2014", "05/12/2015", "06/01/2015", "06/01/2016", "06/02/2015", 
"06/02/2016", "06/03/2015", "06/03/2016", "06/04/2015", "06/04/2016", 
"06/05/2015", "06/06/2015", "06/07/2015", "06/08/2014", "06/08/2015", 
"06/09/2014", "06/09/2015", "06/10/2014", "06/10/2015", "06/11/2014", 
"06/11/2015", "06/12/2014", "06/12/2015", "07/01/2015", "07/01/2016", 
"07/02/2015", "07/02/2016", "07/03/2015", "07/03/2016", "07/04/2015", 
"07/04/2016", "07/05/2015", "07/06/2015", "07/07/2015", "07/08/2014", 
"07/08/2015", "07/09/2014", "07/09/2015", "07/10/2014", "07/10/2015", 
"07/11/2014", "07/11/2015", "07/12/2014", "07/12/2015", "08/01/2015", 
"08/01/2016", "08/02/2015", "08/02/2016", "08/03/2015", "08/03/2016", 
"08/04/2015", "08/04/2016", "08/05/2015", "08/06/2015", "08/07/2015", 
"08/08/2014", "08/08/2015", "08/09/2014", "08/09/2015", "08/10/2014", 
"08/10/2015", "08/11/2014", "08/11/2015", "08/12/2014", "08/12/2015", 
"09/01/2015", "09/01/2016", "09/02/2015", "09/02/2016", "09/03/2015", 
"09/03/2016", "09/04/2015", "09/04/2016", "09/05/2015", "09/06/2015", 
"09/07/2015", "09/08/2014", "09/08/2015", "09/09/2014", "09/09/2015", 
"09/10/2014", "09/10/2015", "09/11/2014", "09/11/2015", "09/12/2014", 
"09/12/2015", "10/01/2015", "10/01/2016", "10/02/2015", "10/02/2016", 
"10/03/2015", "10/03/2016", "10/04/2015", "10/04/2016", "10/05/2015", 
"10/06/2015", "10/07/2015", "10/08/2014", "10/08/2015", "10/09/2014", 
"10/09/2015", "10/10/2014", "10/10/2015", "10/11/2014", "10/11/2015", 
"10/12/2014", "10/12/2015", "11/01/2015", "11/01/2016", "11/02/2015", 
"11/02/2016", "11/03/2015", "11/03/2016", "11/04/2015", "11/04/2016", 
"11/05/2015", "11/06/2015", "11/07/2015", "11/08/2014", "11/08/2015", 
"11/09/2014", "11/09/2015", "11/10/2014", "11/10/2015", "11/11/2014", 
"11/11/2015", "11/12/2014", "11/12/2015", "12/01/2015", "12/01/2016", 
"12/02/2015", "12/02/2016", "12/03/2015", "12/03/2016", "12/04/2015", 
"12/04/2016", "12/05/2015", "12/06/2015", "12/07/2015", "12/08/2014", 
"12/08/2015", "12/09/2014", "12/09/2015", "12/10/2014", "12/10/2015", 
"12/11/2014", "12/11/2015", "12/12/2014", "12/12/2015", "13/01/2015", 
"13/01/2016", "13/02/2015", "13/02/2016", "13/03/2015", "13/03/2016", 
"13/04/2015", "13/04/2016", "13/05/2015", "13/06/2015", "13/07/2015", 
"13/08/2014", "13/08/2015", "13/09/2014", "13/09/2015", "13/10/2014", 
"13/10/2015", "13/11/2014", "13/11/2015", "13/12/2014", "13/12/2015", 
"14/01/2015", "14/01/2016", "14/02/2015", "14/02/2016", "14/03/2015", 
"14/03/2016", "14/04/2015", "14/04/2016", "14/05/2015", "14/06/2015", 
"14/07/2015", "14/08/2014", "14/08/2015", "14/09/2014", "14/09/2015", 
"14/10/2014", "14/10/2015", "14/11/2014", "14/11/2015", "14/12/2014", 
"14/12/2015", "15/01/2015", "15/01/2016", "15/02/2015", "15/02/2016", 
"15/03/2015", "15/03/2016", "15/04/2015", "15/04/2016", "15/05/2015", 
"15/06/2015", "15/07/2015", "15/08/2014", "15/08/2015", "15/09/2014", 
"15/09/2015", "15/10/2014", "15/10/2015", "15/11/2014", "15/11/2015", 
"15/12/2014", "15/12/2015", "16/01/2015", "16/01/2016", "16/02/2015", 
"16/02/2016", "16/03/2015", "16/03/2016", "16/04/2015", "16/04/2016", 
"16/05/2015", "16/06/2015", "16/07/2015", "16/08/2014", "16/08/2015", 
"16/09/2014", "16/09/2015", "16/10/2014", "16/10/2015", "16/11/2014", 
"16/11/2015", "16/12/2014", "16/12/2015", "17/01/2015", "17/01/2016", 
"17/02/2015", "17/02/2016", "17/03/2015", "17/03/2016", "17/04/2015", 
"17/04/2016", "17/05/2015", "17/06/2015", "17/07/2014", "17/07/2015", 
"17/08/2014", "17/08/2015", "17/09/2014", "17/09/2015", "17/10/2014", 
"17/10/2015", "17/11/2014", "17/11/2015", "17/12/2014", "17/12/2015", 
"18/01/2015", "18/01/2016", "18/02/2015", "18/02/2016", "18/03/2015", 
"18/03/2016", "18/04/2015", "18/04/2016", "18/05/2015", "18/06/2015", 
"18/07/2014", "18/07/2015", "18/08/2014", "18/08/2015", "18/09/2014", 
"18/09/2015", "18/10/2014", "18/10/2015", "18/11/2014", "18/11/2015", 
"18/12/2014", "18/12/2015", "19/01/2015", "19/01/2016", "19/02/2015", 
"19/02/2016", "19/03/2015", "19/03/2016", "19/04/2015", "19/04/2016", 
"19/05/2015", "19/06/2015", "19/07/2014", "19/07/2015", "19/08/2014", 
"19/08/2015", "19/09/2014", "19/09/2015", "19/10/2014", "19/10/2015", 
"19/11/2014", "19/11/2015", "19/12/2014", "19/12/2015", "20/01/2015", 
"20/01/2016", "20/02/2015", "20/02/2016", "20/03/2015", "20/03/2016", 
"20/04/2015", "20/04/2016", "20/05/2015", "20/06/2015", "20/07/2014", 
"20/07/2015", "20/08/2014", "20/08/2015", "20/09/2014", "20/09/2015", 
"20/10/2014", "20/10/2015", "20/11/2014", "20/11/2015", "20/12/2014", 
"20/12/2015", "21/01/2015", "21/01/2016", "21/02/2015", "21/02/2016", 
"21/03/2015", "21/03/2016", "21/04/2015", "21/04/2016", "21/05/2015", 
"21/06/2015", "21/07/2014", "21/07/2015", "21/08/2014", "21/08/2015", 
"21/09/2014", "21/09/2015", "21/10/2014", "21/10/2015", "21/11/2014", 
"21/11/2015", "21/12/2014", "21/12/2015", "22/01/2015", "22/01/2016", 
"22/02/2015", "22/02/2016", "22/03/2015", "22/03/2016", "22/04/2015", 
"22/04/2016", "22/05/2015", "22/06/2015", "22/07/2014", "22/07/2015", 
"22/08/2014", "22/08/2015", "22/09/2014", "22/09/2015", "22/10/2014", 
"22/10/2015", "22/11/2014", "22/11/2015", "22/12/2014", "22/12/2015", 
"23/01/2015", "23/01/2016", "23/02/2015", "23/02/2016", "23/03/2015", 
"23/03/2016", "23/04/2015", "23/04/2016", "23/05/2015", "23/06/2015", 
"23/07/2014", "23/07/2015", "23/08/2014", "23/08/2015", "23/09/2014", 
"23/09/2015", "23/10/2014", "23/10/2015", "23/11/2014", "23/11/2015", 
"23/12/2014", "23/12/2015", "24/01/2015", "24/01/2016", "24/02/2015", 
"24/02/2016", "24/03/2015", "24/03/2016", "24/04/2015", "24/04/2016", 
"24/05/2015", "24/06/2015", "24/07/2014", "24/07/2015", "24/08/2014", 
"24/08/2015", "24/09/2014", "24/09/2015", "24/10/2014", "24/10/2015", 
"24/11/2014", "24/11/2015", "24/12/2014", "24/12/2015", "25/01/2015", 
"25/01/2016", "25/02/2015", "25/02/2016", "25/03/2015", "25/03/2016", 
"25/04/2015", "25/05/2015", "25/06/2015", "25/07/2014", "25/07/2015", 
"25/08/2014", "25/08/2015", "25/09/2014", "25/09/2015", "25/10/2014", 
"25/10/2015", "25/11/2014", "25/11/2015", "25/12/2014", "25/12/2015", 
"26/01/2015", "26/01/2016", "26/02/2015", "26/02/2016", "26/03/2015", 
"26/03/2016", "26/04/2015", "26/05/2015", "26/06/2015", "26/07/2014", 
"26/07/2015", "26/08/2014", "26/08/2015", "26/09/2014", "26/09/2015", 
"26/10/2014", "26/10/2015", "26/11/2014", "26/11/2015", "26/12/2014", 
"26/12/2015", "27/01/2015", "27/01/2016", "27/02/2015", "27/02/2016", 
"27/03/2015", "27/03/2016", "27/04/2015", "27/05/2015", "27/06/2015", 
"27/07/2014", "27/07/2015", "27/08/2014", "27/08/2015", "27/09/2014", 
"27/09/2015", "27/10/2014", "27/10/2015", "27/11/2014", "27/11/2015", 
"27/12/2014", "27/12/2015", "28/01/2015", "28/01/2016", "28/02/2015", 
"28/02/2016", "28/03/2015", "28/03/2016", "28/04/2015", "28/05/2015", 
"28/06/2015", "28/07/2014", "28/07/2015", "28/08/2014", "28/08/2015", 
"28/09/2014", "28/09/2015", "28/10/2014", "28/10/2015", "28/11/2014", 
"28/11/2015", "28/12/2014", "28/12/2015", "29/01/2015", "29/01/2016", 
"29/02/2016", "29/03/2015", "29/03/2016", "29/04/2015", "29/05/2015", 
"29/06/2015", "29/07/2014", "29/07/2015", "29/08/2014", "29/08/2015", 
"29/09/2014", "29/09/2015", "29/10/2014", "29/10/2015", "29/11/2014", 
"29/11/2015", "29/12/2014", "29/12/2015", "30/01/2015", "30/01/2016", 
"30/03/2015", "30/03/2016", "30/04/2015", "30/05/2015", "30/06/2015", 
"30/07/2014", "30/07/2015", "30/08/2014", "30/08/2015", "30/09/2014", 
"30/09/2015", "30/10/2014", "30/10/2015", "30/11/2014", "30/11/2015", 
"30/12/2014", "30/12/2015", "31/01/2015", "31/01/2016", "31/03/2015", 
"31/03/2016", "31/05/2015", "31/07/2014", "31/07/2015", "31/08/2014", 
"31/08/2015", "31/10/2014", "31/10/2015", "31/12/2014", "31/12/2015"
), class = "factor"), index = c(11.54043, 14.27814, 11.5583, 
12.37828, 12.54057, 12.10189, 12.12189, 12.28188, 11.96189, 12.35303, 
13.023, 12.55187, 11.04192, 8.722033, 6.952167, 6.732189, 9.022016, 
8.432052, 5.882287, 5.276563, 4.731485, 4.403024, 4.651509, 6.319038, 
7.818936, 7.948929, 6.809, 6.199048, 6.749004, 6.499023, 5.899076, 
4.529247, 4.02078, 3.760833, 3.617566, 3.36093, 3.950794, 4.230742, 
4.320727, 4.720667, 4.570688, 4.080769, 4.360721, 4.580687, 4.730665, 
4.630679, 4.960635, 4.180751, 4.270736, 4.210746, 4.440708, 3.670853, 
3.570877, 3.650858, 3.740838, 3.880808, 3.840816, 3.240964, 3.160988, 
3.250961, 3.580874, 3.560879, 5.380586, 4.510697, 4.390716, 4.260737, 
3.890806, 3.36093, 3.721801, 3.591829, 3.560497, 4.120431, 4.55039, 
4.4404, 4.470397, 4.670381, 3.660484, 3.730475, 3.160559, 3.320533, 
3.380523, 3.600492, 3.030583, 3.260542, 2.970594, 3.040581, 2.99059, 
3.40052, 3.730475, 3.430516, 3.530501, 2.970594, 3.820464, 3.830463, 
3.870458, 3.700479, 3.710477, 3.680481, 3.490507, 3.740474, 3.260542, 
3.318999, 3.298999, 3.328999, 3.368284, 3.41828, 3.238295, 3.008317, 
2.878331, 2.788342, 2.598366, 2.488382, 2.468385, 2.448388, 2.548373, 
2.308412, 2.448388, 2.658358, 2.048463, 2.568371, 2.838336, 2.868332, 
2.998318, 3.358285, 3.118306, 2.618364, 2.478384, 3.1783, 3.018316, 
3.07831, 2.898329, 2.938325, 2.88833, 2.848335, 2.948324, 2.908328, 
2.958322, 2.968321, 2.736638, 2.927969, 2.95236, 2.92152, 4.159778, 
3.274662, 3.716456, 4.321648, 4.33252, 4.942867, 4.324445, 3.925162, 
3.485163, 3.945088, 3.467801, 3.84071, 3.542677, 3.207959, 3.097636, 
3.229113, 3.049058, 3.487368, 2.946642, 3.194158, 3.033129, 2.741163, 
2.646968, 2.514944, 2.612467, 2.806449, 2.708465, 2.567833, 2.783192, 
2.99844, 2.858031, 2.860846, 2.422666, 2.08108, 2.192705, 2.407469, 
2.951197, 2.425093, 2.561358, 2.162087, 2.164641, 2.295119, 1.817072, 
1.385466, 2.399334, 2.859039, 2.098575, 2.406024, 2.369869, 2.744476, 
3.224035, 2.8761, 2.99883, 3.079353, 2.99788, 2.957237, 2.329897, 
2.556688, 2.261765, 2.211449, 2.077952, 2.172062, 2.501332, 2.271251, 
2.567649, 1.985015, 2.011745, 2.378133, 1.937532, 2.295658, 1.967439, 
1.922405, 1.77076, 1.877509, 1.903558, 1.843825, 2.033853, 2.107302, 
2.038126, 2.054973, 1.993873, 2.042604, 1.981318, 2.286632, 1.902597, 
2.202905, 2.262768, 2.493253, 2.105771, 2.113826, 2.7515, 2.085522, 
2.613089, 2.118656, 2.310738, 2.626212, 2.629956, 2.752603, 2.746964, 
2.766788, 2.696453, 2.159032, 2.134599, 1.714365, 1.55678, 1.626582, 
1.607851, 1.532417, 1.571745, 1.500041, 1.543227, 1.480322, 1.762261, 
1.515217, 1.304601, 1.447073, 1.475861, 1.498862, 1.573622, 1.515242, 
1.606151, 1.581706, 1.443625, 1.442918, 1.450428, 1.56483, 1.502704, 
1.555937, 1.593459, 1.459013, 1.365548, 1.530271, 1.522306, 1.164105, 
1.449812, 1.34549, 1.277848, 1.140585, 1.035555, 1.161103, 1.085743, 
1.174396, 1.188879, 1.245301, 0.985737, 1.169837, 1.21196, 1.132433, 
1.199008, 1.16729, 1.176818, 1.202165, 1.191286, 1.199928, 1.16782, 
1.163427, 1.147315, 1.152607, 1.229492, 1.464407, 1.35002, 1.326579, 
1.254948, 1.333277, 0.965398, 1.246482, 1.068102, 1.05843, 1.15212, 
1.182821, 1.328945, 1.261149, 1.319696, 0.815034, 1.242683, 1.222728, 
1.351629, 1.311053, 1.299895, 1.161236, 0.913985, 1.021523, 0.974081, 
1.312736, 0.84724, 0.784337, 0.910343, 0.911839, 0.988695, 1.204447, 
1.188309, 1.209292, 1.269653, 1.131285, 1.196762, 1.122018, 1.278813, 
1.306997, 1.507417, 1.808925, 1.422698, 1.362512, 1.456492, 1.339841, 
1.408134, 1.464803, 1.472624, 1.507043, 1.55663, 1.48721, 1.481805, 
1.350952, 1.394053, 1.505662, 1.552468, 1.835227, 1.529406, 1.542733, 
2.472506, 2.051214, 2.04605, 2.332706, 2.51142, 2.856563, 2.625034, 
2.642861, 2.351145, 2.318266, 2.551799, 2.332817, 2.073351, 1.730547, 
2.268209, 2.08866, 1.918522, 2.225836, 2.343466, 2.1983, 2.214688, 
2.249369, 2.320987, 2.158788, 2.250545, 1.86419, 1.960187, 2.145659, 
1.785818, 1.812893, 1.670426, 1.759863, 1.930967, 1.911622, 1.682475, 
1.77137, 1.566444, 1.802325, 1.586361, 1.294167, 1.483635, 1.699373, 
1.980278, 1.628827, 2.130249, 1.65064, 1.830685, 2.334663, 2.239406, 
2.374907, 2.174426, 2.11795, 1.962688, 1.970793, 2.334288, 1.97112, 
2.109338, 2.380336, 1.974693, 2.231339, 1.150346, 1.248199, 1.104014, 
1.145332, 1.376, 1.365866, 1.431675, 1.411714, 1.470395, 1.463537, 
1.479107, 1.571953, 1.582307, 1.425284, 1.357404, 1.459058, 1.29251, 
2.079904, 2.043994, 2.02053, 1.854421, 2.024019, 2.027243, 2.024739, 
2.020098, 2.072994, 1.89817, 1.970579, 1.925721, 1.940698, 1.958429, 
1.97927, 1.990377, 2.545347, 2.343933, 2.110605, 2.372304, 2.614607, 
2.65837, 1.253188, 2.371879, 2.48065, 2.581769, 2.201459, 1.705221, 
2.662408, 1.769794, 2.160805, 1.933198, 2.318748, 2.279574, 2.206514, 
1.86008, 2.221785, 2.732116, 2.876525, 2.45854, 2.093711, 1.990731, 
2.119744, 1.88928, 1.906683, 1.711405, 1.290373, 1.965132, 1.639966, 
1.579937, 1.896039, 1.955329, 1.970785, 1.41028, 1.963055, 1.935048, 
1.958985, 1.912964, 1.915689, 1.844459, 2.267502, 2.263569, 2.260751, 
1.863576, 1.810112, 1.739387, 1.646463, 1.552307, 1.871372, 1.735762, 
1.694135, 1.627406, 1.789137, 1.636116, 1.65404, 1.655442, 1.466584, 
1.630533, 1.474457, 1.505985, 1.435338, 1.537106, 1.521365, 1.464372, 
1.450722, 1.387195, 1.432416, 1.409623, 1.943541, 1.895353, 1.727831, 
1.915016, 2.142965, 1.78175, 1.757019, 4.046341, 2.268203, 1.695811, 
1.714067, 1.689575, 1.810448, 1.587102, 1.83034, 1.513751, 1.535203, 
1.531233, 1.43809, 1.390571, 1.292746, 1.3538, 1.201273, 1.481288, 
1.600983, 1.438571, 1.583992, 1.766542, 1.717157, 1.773975, 1.95323, 
2.0458, 1.965663, 1.868745, 1.862877, 1.717166, 1.85268, 1.865566, 
2.831913, 1.858382, 1.926938, 1.911859, 2.364972, 2.271169, 2.147911, 
2.273932, 2.173164, 2.235003, 2.160419, 2.58684, 2.440009, 2.334429, 
2.374356, 2.637341, 2.751997, 2.662583, 2.570964, 2.643219, 2.196613, 
2.226018, 2.142688, 2.403963, 2.384954, 2.661776, 2.711935, 2.714279, 
2.329776, 2.370735, 2.100872, 1.943771, 1.575529, 1.544865, 1.51201, 
1.443336, 1.655716, 1.664355, 1.717507, 1.717282, 1.806321, 1.788896, 
1.803193, 1.401859, 1.762782, 1.537422, 2.145965, 2.305251, 2.110511, 
1.934735, 1.946052, 2.138253, 2.025721, 1.993805, 2.072526, 1.888899, 
1.803845, 1.830216, 1.821895, 1.843385, 1.999159, 1.951067, 1.889941, 
2.360204, 2.645206, 2.347469, 2.241971, 2.043113, 1.962672, 1.903516, 
1.609725, 1.71036, 1.801525, 1.748996, 1.566542, 1.588622, 1.507817, 
1.629962, 1.669554, 1.624924, 1.555608, 1.474775, 1.438227, 1.664659, 
1.499378)), .Names = c("time", "index"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-648L))
```

So, what I generally do is to write this code:

```
library(fBasics)

pw_index <- read.csv("~/data/index.csv",
                 header=T)

# Set time in date format
index$time <- as.Date(index$time, format="%d/%m/%y")

index <- index[order(index$time), ]

# Save the date in a separate identifier as character
dates = as.character(index$time)
index <- index[order(dates), ]

# Convert the data frame to an .xts object:
index_xts <- as.xts(index$index, order.by=index$time)

head(index_xts)
```

If I initially inspect the dataset vie `head()` I obtain this:

```
    time           index
    <fctr>         <dbl>
1   17/07/2014  11.54043        
2   18/07/2014  14.27814        
3   19/07/2014  11.55830        
4   20/07/2014  12.37828        
5   21/07/2014  12.54057        
6   22/07/2014  12.10189
```

However, what I do obtain after the code is a completely messed out dataset (last observation should be of 2016...):

```
               [,1]
2020-01-01 2.708465
2020-01-01 2.268203
2020-01-02 2.567833
2020-01-02 1.695811
2020-01-03 2.783192
2020-01-03 1.714067
```

Who knows what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is somewhat convoluted, and I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do. For converting the data in your `data.frame` into an `xts` object you can do the following:

```
library(xts);
xts <- xts(x = df$index, order.by = as.POSIXct(df$time, format = "%d/%m/%Y"));
tail(xts);
#               [,1]
#2016-04-19 1.624924
#2016-04-20 1.555608
#2016-04-21 1.474775
#2016-04-22 1.438227
#2016-04-23 1.664659
#2016-04-24 1.499378
```

I assume that `df` is your `data.frame` the content of which you provided with `dput`.